# Sticking together double entries in a for loop

Tags: php, json, for-loop

I have a list of rounds & teams from a JSON page like so...

```
ROUND | TEAM
-------------
6     | D.C. United
7     | (blank)
8     | New York Red Bulls
8     | Los Angeles Galaxy
9     | Portland Timbers
10    | Chivas USA
11    | Seattle Sounders FC
11    | Houston Dynamo
12    | D.C. United
```

At the moment, I am echoing it out like shown above, but I would like for any double rounds to show both teams together rather than separately.

Here's an example of what I want to show...

```
ROUND | TEAM
-------------
6     | D.C. United
7     | (blank)
8     | New York Red Bulls & Los Angeles Galaxy
9     | Portland Timbers
10    | Chivas USA
11    | Seattle Sounders FC & Houston Dynamo
12    | D.C. United
```

Here's what I'm using right now.... I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
//get the page 
$str = file_get_contents('http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/498/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

//count how many entries
$howmanyrounds = count($jsonarray['fixtures']['all']);

//for each entry
for($whichround = 0; $whichround < $howmanyrounds; $whichround++)
{
    //this returns a value like 'Round 6'
    $gameweek = $jsonarray['fixtures']['all'][$whichround][1];
    //Cut out just the number
    $roundno = intval(substr($gameweek, -(strlen($gameweek)-6)));

    //this returns a value like 'Chivas USA (H)'
    $opponents = $jsonarray['fixtures']['all'][$whichround][2];
    //This cuts out the actual team name
    $team = substr($opponents, 0, (strlen($opponents)-4));

    echo $roundno." ".$team."<br>";
}
```

I have tried a few different ways which all ended up not working anyway close to what I want. This should be pretty easy. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: `substr($gameweek, -(strlen($gameweek)-6)) == substr($gameweek, 6)` :)

Comment: Thanks. My way works too but is just a bit weird and overcomplicated I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try joining the values into an indexed array:

```
$arrJoined = array();

for($whichround = 0; $whichround < $howmanyrounds; $whichround++)
{
    //this returns a value like 'Round 6'
    $gameweek = $jsonarray['fixtures']['all'][$whichround][1];
    //Cut out just the number
    $roundno = intval(substr($gameweek, -(strlen($gameweek)-6)));

    //this returns a value like 'Chivas USA (H)'
    $opponents = $jsonarray['fixtures']['all'][$whichround][2];
    //This cuts out the actual team name
    $team = substr($opponents, 0, (strlen($opponents)-4));

    $arrJoined[$roundno] = ($arrJoined[$roundno] == null ? $team : $arrJoined[$roundno].' & '.$team);
}
```

Then just output the contents of your $arrJoined.

Comment: Thanks.. This does seem to work, but now I need to get it to ignore all the blank array entries from  $arrJoined[1] to  $arrJoined[5]. I should be able to manage that (I think) - thanks!

Comment: No problem! also there is no blank array entries, try print_r($arrJoined); :)

Comment: Oh.. yeah I confused it. More what I meant is that the number starts at 6 in this case and will be different depending on the week it's run, so I need to work around it, but that should be manageable also.

Comment: Ah, yeah - just use foreach to loop through $arrJoined instead of a regular for loop. You also get free sorting in your array by using the method i provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an intermediate array to group the teams together based on round no.:

```
$rounds = array();

for($whichround = 0; $whichround < $howmanyrounds; $whichround++)
{
    // ...
    $rounds[$roundno][] = $team;
}

foreach ($rounds as $roundno => $teams) {
    echo $roundno . " " . join(' & ', $teams)."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this as intermediate array and you should be good

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/498/');
            $array = json_decode($str, true);
            $temp = $array['fixtures']['all'];
            $req_array = array();
            foreach($temp as $value)
            {
                list($dummy, $round)  = explode(" ", $value[1]);
                           $value[2] = str_replace('-','',$value[2]);
                if(isset($req_array["Round $round"]) 
                   && ($req_array["Round $round"] != '') 
                   )
                {
                    $req_array["Round $round"] = $req_array["Round $round"]."&".$value[2];
                }
                else if($value[2] != '-')
                {
                    $req_array["Round $round"] = $value[2];
                }
            }
```

**output** of `$req_array`

```
  Array
   (
    [Round 6] => D.C. United (H)
[Round 7] => 
[Round 8] => New York Red Bulls (A)&Los Angeles Galaxy (A)
[Round 9] => Portland Timbers (H)
[Round 10] => Chivas USA (H)
[Round 11] => Seattle Sounders FC (H)&Houston Dynamo (A)
[Round 12] => D.C. United (A)
 ---
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What i suggest, just another array (targetAray) in you code and push the data in that array and than print that array like below:

```
$targetArray = array();   //additional array to store values
//count how many entries
$howmanyrounds = count($jsonarray['fixtures']['all']);

//for each entry
for($whichround = 0; $whichround < $howmanyrounds; $whichround++)
{
    //this returns a value like 'Round 6'
    $gameweek = $jsonarray['fixtures']['all'][$whichround][1];

    //Cut out just the number
    $roundno = intval(substr($gameweek, -(strlen($gameweek)-6)));

    //this returns a value like 'Chivas USA (H)'
    $opponents = $jsonarray['fixtures']['all'][$whichround][2];
    //This cuts out the actual team name
    $team = substr($opponents, 0, (strlen($opponents)-4));

   //below code you need to add. 
   if(array_key_exists($roundno, $targetArray))
     $targetArray[$roundno] = $targetArray[$roundno]. "&" .$team;
   else
    $targetArray[$roundno] = $team;
    echo $roundno." ".$team."<br>";
}
//this will give you your data
print_r($targetArray);
```